# Как правильно подключить виджет через ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Добрый день, в процессе разработки столкнулся с одной проблемой.

При нажатии на кнопку отправляется ajax запрос и возвращает инициализированный виджет. Проблема в том, что в возвращаеться все без ошибки, но не работает js и css не подключается. использую в [виджете](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#settings) сторонний плагин.
Результат - бесконечно крутящийся спиннер, хотя должно быть поле с тегами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так делаю запрос:

```
    $.ajax('/user/employee-manage/load-tags', {
       type: 'post',
       data: {
              'ids' : employeesChecked
       },
       success: function (response) {
                $('.panel-employee-tag').append(response)

       }
  });
```

Контроллер возвращает результат в формате JSON:

```
public function actionLoadTags()
{
      return TagsPanelWidget::widget();
}
```

Шаблон виджета:

```
<?php
use kartik\select2\Select2;
?>
<?= Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'color_2',
    'value' => ['red', 'green'],
    'maintainOrder' => true,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a employees ...',        'multiple' => true],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
    ],
]);
?>
```

Результат возвращается в таком виде:

```
<span id="parent-s2-togall-w0" style="display:none"><span id="s2-togall-w0" class="s2-togall-button s2-togall-select"><span class="s2-select-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>Выбрать все</span><span class="s2-unselect-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>Отменить выбор</span></span></span><div class="kv-plugin-loading loading-w0">&nbsp;</div><select id="w0" class="form-control" name="color_2[]" multiple size="4" data-s2-options="s2options_ae5051fd" data-krajee-select2="select2_11baaf42" style="display:none">
<option value="red" selected>red</option>
<option value="green" selected>green</option>
</select>
```

**Я подозреваю, что проблема в том, что не подгружает js в самом плагине. 
Как возможно исправить эту проблему ?**

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы Yii2 рендерил винджет вместе с css и js, необходимо в контроллере отправлять view функцией renderAjax();

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! 
А если не view  а виджет в таком виде, как я привел в примере ?